# How to Compare 2 objects and find if a particular property has changed and if yes, set flag to false

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 2 objects and I want to compare both. If any of the slug properties have changed(added, modified, or deleted) I want the flag to be set to false. Any other change or no changes, I want the flag as true. What is the best way to achieve it through ES6 or lodash? The blow one wil be false since we have a new object in the array and also one of the slug properties has been modified

**OBJECT1**

```
{
    "id": "111111",
    "title": "ParentTitle1",
    "featuredTitle": [
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle1",
            "slug": "title1"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle2",
            "slug": "title2"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle3",
            "slug": "title3"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle4",
            "slug": "title4"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle5",
            "slug": "title5"
        }
    ]
}
```

**OBJECT2**

```
{
    "id": "111111",
    "title": "ParentTitle2",
    "featuredTitle": [
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle1",
            "slug": "titlenew1"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitlenew2",
            "slug": "title2"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle3",
            "slug": "title3"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle4",
            "slug": "title4"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle5",
            "slug": "title5"
        },
        {
            "title": "ChildTitle6",
            "slug": "title6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if two have the same slugs, but in different order? Is it possible for two slugs to have the same `slug` value?

Answer (score 0):

Making these assumptions:

- Only the content of the `featuredTitle` array is relevant for the comparison
- The order of that array is not relevant. If a second object just has the same array but in shuffled order, the function should return true
- The inner objects always have exactly two properties `slug`, `title`

You could map the the inner objects to arrays, consisting of two values: the slug and the title. Then sort that array of pairs, and finally serialize it to JSON. If this JSON is the same for two objects, then the function should return true, otherwise false.

Here is an implementation:

```js
const asString = object => JSON.stringify(
        object.featuredTitle.map(({title, slug}) => [slug, title])
              .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
    );
const isSame = (a, b) => asString(a) === asString(b);

// The example objects from the question:
const object1 = {"id": "111111","title": "ParentTitle1","featuredTitle": [{"title": "ChildTitle1","slug": "title1"},{"title": "ChildTitle2","slug": "title2"},{"title": "ChildTitle3","slug": "title3"},{"title": "ChildTitle4","slug": "title4"},{"title": "ChildTitle5","slug": "title5"}]};
const object2 = {"id": "111111","title": "ParentTitle2","featuredTitle": [{"title": "ChildTitle1","slug": "titlenew1"},{"title": "ChildTitlenew2","slug": "title2"},{"title": "ChildTitle3","slug": "title3"},{"title": "ChildTitle4","slug": "title4"},{"title": "ChildTitle5","slug": "title5"},{"title": "ChildTitle6","slug": "title6"}]};

console.log(isSame(object1, object2)); // false
```